# A class of non-convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

What are some examples of not necessarily convex functions mapping $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which are smooth, have gradients of bounded norm and have a global/local minima? I would be delighted see some non-trivial non-oscillating parametric families of such functions!

The easiest examples of this type that I can think of are $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Any arctangent function fits this description.

Comment: Sorry! I had a typo. Please see the question now.

Comment: Any arctangent function restricted to $[a,\infty)$ for finite $a<0$ fits this description.

Comment: I do not want to bound the domain. I am always thinking of functions defined on the whole R^n

Comment: Then that should also be a requirement.

Comment: Okay. Let me put that in too.

Comment: Functions like $e^{-1/x^2}$ fit this description.

Comment: Thanks! I would like to get many more if you can help :)

Comment: Here's an interesting class of functions; note this includes some which are not smooth, though. https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.04466

Comment: @MichaelGrant Why is star-convex function bounded gradient?

Comment: It's not necessarily. I'm just pointing out that for general interest. That's why it's a comment not an answer ;-)